# filter not behaving as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

In my index.html, I have this:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="title" list="comicstitle">
<datalist id="comicstitle">
    <option  data-ng-repeat="ttl in titles | filter: title" value="{{ttl.name}}">
</datalist>
```

and in my controller,

```
$scope.titles = [{ name: "Software Engineering", category: 1 }, 
                 { name: "Architect",       category: 2 }, 
                 { name: "Software Engineering1", category: 1 }];
```

When I type the word Software, Software Engineering and Software Engineering1 comes-out in my datalist. However, when I am entering Eng or Engineering..Nothing is returned in the datalist.

How am I supposed to do filtering not by StartsWith but "Contains"?

Comment: The [AngularJS](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter) docs explain how to use this built-in filter function. From the docs, it sounds like it should filter by "substring match in case insensitive way" by default, which is what you want. If you create a Plunkr or JSFiddle, I can try to help debug.

Comment: Hi @jelinson, here is the fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/r8JL7/9/

Comment: The jsfiddle does what you want it to do. If I type "Eng", the data list presents the two Software Engineering options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having isn't with angular per se, it's with html5 datalist. Some documentation is here: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-datalist/

EDIT: It looks like browsers handle datalist differently. Chrome apparently only will do "StartsWith", but firefox will use a "Contains"

The datalist autocomplete only supports "StartsWith" not "Contains". You'll have to use separate JS to implement the autocomplete as you'd want it. Here is a pretty good place to start (although it does require jQuery UI):

(I did not write this - I'm just linking to it and copying code here)
http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/
Code on jsfiddle includes jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.16:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='MyModule'>
    <div ng-controller='DefaultCtrl'>
        <input auto-complete ui-items="names" ng-model="selected">
        selected = {{selected}}
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function DefaultCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["john", "bill", "charlie", "robert", "alban", "oscar", "marie", "celine", "brad", "drew", "rebecca", "michel", "francis", "jean", "paul", "pierre", "nicolas", "alfred", "gerard", "louis", "albert", "edouard", "benoit", "guillaume", "nicolas", "joseph"];
}

angular.module('MyModule', []).directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
                select: function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                      iElement.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
    };
});
```